# Javascript Click Event handler is not triggered when Playwright click is made

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, playwright, playwright-python

For one of the `Automation` cases written in `Playwright Python`, there is a need to listen to clicked element and get it's bounding box for further validation.

As the playwright documentation doesn't have any event handlers specific to click on given page, tried below Javascript event handler with combination of `JS and Playwright in Python`.

However found that click made through Playwright method is not triggering any click event for JS to capture.

If I click on the page manually the event is getting triggered.

1. Am I missing any small thing? Or it is not supported in Playwright?
2. Is there any other alternative to capture all clicks in Playwright?

The running code in Python is as below

```
import asyncio
import time
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


async def main():
    playwright = await async_playwright().start()
    browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.new_page(viewport={"width": 1880, "height": 900})
    client = await page.context.new_cdp_session(page)

    print("successfully opened browser")
    url = 'https://www.cricbuzz.com/'
    await page.goto(url=url if "://" in url else "http://" + url)

    time.sleep(3)
    ### Code goes here ###
    js = """
    clickEvent = null;
    console.log("Adding Click handler")
    window.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
        console.log("Click handler called "+e.clientX+"||"+e.clientY); 
        console.log(e); 
        clickEvent=5;});
    let startTime = new Date();
    while(clickEvent==null){
        let endTime = new Date();
        if(endTime - startTime>10000)
        break;
    };
    """

    window_handle = page.evaluate_handle(js)
    await page.mouse.click(100, 100)

    clickCompleted = await window_handle

    clickEventObjectDirect = await page.evaluate("clickEvent")
    print(clickEventObjectDirect)
    clickEventObject = page.evaluate_handle("clickEvent")
    clickEventObjectTemp = await clickEventObject
    clickEventObjectJSON = await clickEventObjectTemp.json_value()
    print(clickEventObjectJSON)

    print("Waiting")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Suggestion: please avoid `adding` backticks to `words that aren't code`. It's very `distracting`. Thanks. As for your programming problem, what is the goal you're trying to achieve here, exactly? Clicking specific X/Y coordinates is very brittle, and almost never should be done. What's the purpose of the `while` loop?

Comment: Objective: Need to listen to any click event on Page and get its Point position to check it later if it belongs to a valid Bouding Box obtained separately.

Comment: This code example was workaround to the objective, tried to listen to click event through Plain Javascript and added while loop for timeout.

Comment: Why do you need to validate that it belongs to a valid bounding box? What exactly is the application functionality to the user, you are ultimately trying to validate?

Comment: I have automated thousands of different scenarios myself in playwright but never came across a requirement like that so curious what is the business use case here.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal, I would say it's confidential. But can reveal that, "Click" action will be performed by some other code and need to verify that click happened on expected element. Either event should be captured on what element happened or have to validate as per the workaround.